# Kendo Autocomplete no matched result

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Autocomplete and would like to display a 'not found' message
when there is no matched result. How can I do that?

I had tried the following code, but the pop-up will disappear immediately:

```
        kendo.ui.AutoComplete.fn.search = (function (search){
            return function(word) {
                word = word || this._accessor();

                search.apply(this, arguments);

                if(this.dataSource.view().length === 0) {
                    $('#txtMapFilterSearch_listbox').append("<li tabindex='-1' role='option' unselectable='on' class='k-item'>Not found</li>");
                }
            };
        })(kendo.ui.AutoComplete.fn.search);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the following link at Telerik site

[How to add a No Records Found template in Kendo AutoComplete widget](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/autocomplete/how-to/add-no-records-custom-template)